# get value assigned for the JButton

Tags: java, swing

How can I get the value of a JButton in its Action Listener?

I will explain the scenario:
I have created the JButton and set its properties

```
cDelete.setValue("Delete1");    
cDelete.setText("DELETE");
```

In its ActionListener,

```
if(e.getActionCommand().contains("DELETE"))
{
// get the value of invoked button i.e,: Delete1
}
```

While I am trying `e.getActionCommand()`, I am getting the text in button: `DELETE`.
I want to get `Delete1`.

Comment: `JButton button = ((JButton) e.getSource());`

With this you can get a reference to the button

Comment: What do you mean by value ??